Cannot solve for Xcode being unable to find image_picker_ios in Flutter app
I have been unable to solve for this error despite following all the suggestions on other similar stackoverflow questions. I am using image_picker: ^1.1.2, iOS 13 and Xcode 16. When I try to run my Flutter app on the iOS simulator from Android Studio it works fine. When I try run it in Xcode, I get the error "'/Users/[user]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gcahfxqobhbhgncufigmdneropvn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/image_picker_ios' not found"
I have tried all the usual suspects:

Reinstalled cocoapods, repo update etc.
Flutter clean, flutter pub get etc.
Clearing XCode derived data
Trying to manually fix Xcode search paths
Deleting and recreating ios folder

I am at a bit of a loss as to why this keeps happening! And I am wondering if there is an actual bug using this addin on Xcode? I am working on an M1 Pro.
